# kubernetes helm changes storageClassName if provided value is blank

Tags: kubernetes, helm3

**Initial helm install with following parameters is successfully deployed:**

```
  persistance:
    storageClassName: ''
    size: 5Gi
```

**After no change to above parameters i try to upgrade the helm the helm returns the following error:**

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: cannot patch "pvc" with kind PersistentVolumeClaim: PersistentVolumeClaim "pvc" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: spec is immutable after creation except resources.requests for bound claims
  core.PersistentVolumeClaimSpec{
        ... // 2 identical fields
        Resources:        {Requests: {s"storage": {i: {...}, s: "5Gi", Format: "BinarySI"}}},
        VolumeName:       "pvc-f85b49fe-5656-4d92-a400-6a333e11a00e",
-       StorageClassName: nil,
+       StorageClassName: &"standard",
        VolumeMode:       &"Filesystem",
        DataSource:       nil,
        DataSourceRef:    nil,
  }
```

This happens due to default storage class which is **standard** in my case. Therefore helm tries to modify the storageClassName to "standard" from "nil" when i upgrade.

How to prevent changes to this value and ask helm to always use default no matter the default is "standard" or "gp2" or anything else.

Comment: One way to overcome is to use the values as same as the name of your default storageClass but which changes for different environment. Like 
```
  persistance:
    storageClassName: 'standard'
    size: 5Gi
```
 (gp2 on AWS, standard on ## GKE, AWS & OpenStack)

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Using AWS eks with kubernetes 1.20.
But it really doesn't matter as its the problem by helm template engine

Comment: Your problem looks like connected to wrong helm chart. Could you add your full helm chart (template) to the question?

Comment: Helm chart is perfectly working when i apply it for the first time as i have mentioned. It only doesn't work when i try to upgrade it.. I tried even without changing any values..

Comment: Yes, I understand. However, without the entire helm chart, I won't be able to help you as there is a good chance the problem is with a part you didn't provide. Also please provide what I asked for in the previous question.